# How can I remove safari website data difficult to remove stored by these websites?

Tags: website, safari

How can I remove safari website data difficult to remove stored by these websites?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5EWu.png)

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS** devices, follow these steps:

1. Go to "Settings"
2. Scroll and select "Safari"
3. Scroll and select "Clear History and Website Data"

For **macOS**, follow these steps:

1. Launch Safari
2. In the menu bar, click on "Safari"
3. Select "Preferences"
4. Then, go to the "Privacy" tab
5. Click the "Remove All Website Data..." button

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hi Sam. 

I have done this and its not working. That's why I wrote and that's what I mentioned that I am removing them again and again but all others go away these stays as such. That's the problem. I have followed this after Google out the all possible ways but fact is that these nasty sites stay there even after all possible ways I remove them. 


Thanks.